# Oracle 9.2 - DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE

Tags: oracle, oracle9i

The function `DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE()` has been added since Oracle 10. There is a way in Oracle 9 to have the same call stack ?

I need to use it in my production package where an exeption is raised and to check the "line" when this is raised.

Answer (score 1):

In short, no.

Depending on exactly what information you need, you may be able to make do with `DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_STACK` or `DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_CALL_STACK`, which I think were introduced much earlier, around Oracle 7.

Comment: The problem is that i have an exception when others that wrap a lot of code and is really hard to debug........